# Facebook SwitchUserSample not working with API v2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to copy the functionality of the SwitchUserSample Facebook project. This project shows how it's possible to manage multiple Facebook users in one app.

When I switch the Facebook sample project to use the Facebook Graph v2.0 the sample project stops working as it should. Rather than silently logging the new user in, it prompts them to enter their username and password each time.

Does anyone know of a workaround or solution to this problem?

Steps to repeat:

1) Download the sample project:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/samples/SwitchUserSample

2) Create a new app in the Facebook developer area - new apps will use the v2.0 API

3) Compile the app and add a new user to a slot

4) Toggle the user - rather than silently logging in, it will show a login dialog

Comment: You should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs so we can fix it

Comment: Bug filed here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1423934037871644/